Render as values the image's attributes (src, alt, width and height) in ds1-col.html.twig
I need to render the image's attributes (src, alt, width and height) from a ds1-col.html.twig (Display Suite) in a node.
I can render strings using {{ ds_content.node_title }}, however... I don't know how to do with the field_cover_image referenced from the media module.

Using dump {{ dump(ds_content) }} throws this:



The field_cover_image is a reference to a media entity image.
URL: /admin/structure/types/manage/my_node/fields.




The reference image.
URL: /admin/structure/media/manage/image/fields.



Are you trying to render the image with these attributes, or literally print these attributes to the node?

Print these attributes in the twig

You can retrieve the Image from the media field with field_cover_image.entity, and the values you want should be on that entity somewhere.
